# Span numbered list

Tags: css, html

I have a list of span elements inside a div:

```
<div id="mediaListHolder"> 
        <span class="content_wrapper"> 
            <div class="hap_media_item"></div>
        </span>
        <span class="content_wrapper"> 
            <div class="hap_media_item"></div>
        </span>
        <span class="content_wrapper"> 
            <div class="hap_media_item"></div>
        </span>
</div>
```

I would like  to place numbers in front of span items like it was an ordered list.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nqq3c/2/

Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: is it out of the question to use javascript?

Comment: Something like http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/nqq3c/5/

Answer (score 3):

a Div inside a span is not legit HTML. Block elements do not go inside of inline elements.

You can, however set the span to display:`list-item` -- you'd also need to use `list-style-type` attribute as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp)

Note, I've not actually done this, but it's what would need to happen providing the browser allows it.

Comment: What if I replace span with div, then it would be legit I guess. As for the numbers, maybe another div could be place in front of each content_wrapper, is it possible?